# How do I set up ember-cli to get at the values in a JSON file

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How do I set up ember-cli to get at the values with the keys "remaining", "success" and "deck_id" from the following JSON file?

I can see in my console>Network>HXR that I am receiving JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
   "remaining": 49,
   "success": true,
   "deck_id": "79n773qlsciez",
   "cards": [
      {
         "suit": "HEARTS",
         "image": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/JH.png",
         "images": {
            "svg": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/JH.svg",
            "png": "http://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/JH.png"
         },
         "code": "JH",
         "value": "JACK"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the rest of my setup:

```
//adapters/card.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: "https://deckofcardsapi.com",
    namespace: "api/deck/79n773qlsciez/draw/",

    pathForType(){
        return "?count=1";
    }
});
```

and

```
//app/models/card.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

image: DS.attr("string"),
code: DS.attr("string")
});
```

and

```
//app/serializers/card.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
     primaryKey: 'code',

});
```

and

```
//app/routes/cards.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
    return this.store.findAll("card");
    }
});
```

and last but not least

```
//templates/cards.hbs
<h2>All cards here</h2>

{{suffle-deck}}
{{#each model as |card|}}
<img src="{{card.image}}" alt="">
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cards are embedded in the JSON suit representation. By default, Ember Data looks for identifiers there.

In order to unserialize the embedded cards, you'll need to use [EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html) in the suit's serializer. This will allow for the cards to be unserialized along with the suit.